# How to use AWS route 53 dns server with a godaddy domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, godaddy-api

I have a godaddy domain and i want to use it with one of my Route53 hosted zone.

When I try to enter my own server names, i'm getting a "InvalidNameserEntry" error.

(I dit this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-inactive.html)

Godaddy phone support tell me that the problem is a special requirement of .fr domain name (ok, seems legit) which need an "authoritative dns server".

And they tell me that aws route 53 dns servers are not authoritative. And I found it a little hard to belive.

What can I do to make this work ?

Thanks !

Comment: They are [authoritative](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/route-53-concepts.html#route-53-concepts-authoritative-name-server): "Route 53 name servers are the authoritative name servers for every domain that uses Route 53 as the DNS service. "

Comment: I got the same problem for a month and godaddy support does not help.  I tried to put the given Route53 dns in godaddy but also got the same error.  I added new ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com but also rejected.

Comment: Finally I ask goddady for refund and registered a domain on aws ...